# Calculating the difference of certain rows of groups in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's assume I have this dataframe:

```
df
    ID  Latitude Longitude Counter
 1  AAA 41.00009 5.0005    1
 2  AAA 41.00015 5.0052    2
 3  AAA 41.00033 5.0142    3
 4  BBB 40.00322 6.4234    1
 5  BBB 40.23421 6.4432    2
 ...
 33 JJJ 39.41002 6.7643    4
 34 JJJ 39.41232 6.7723    5
```

How do I **calculate the difference** between the **last Lat/Lon values of one ID to the first Lat/Lon value of the other** for **every pairs of IDs** then **return** the pairs with the difference at certain range?  For example: Last Lat/Lon of ID "AAA" and first Lat/Lon of ID "BBB" 
Thank you very much! I was thinking using for loop with 2 items.

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')['Latitude','Longitude'].apply(lambda x : x.iloc[0,:]-x.iloc[-1,:])
`

Comment: calculate the difference between ID not within ID ...